# ¿Cómo guardar una frase en un string de forma invertida(al revés)?

Tags: c, string

Tengo este código en lenguaje C y lo que busco es guardar la frase introducida por teclado en otro string pero al revés no entiendo por que no funciona.
    #include

```
#include <string.h>

#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 1000

int main (void)
{
    int i,j,k;//Indices.
    char frase[MAX],invertida[MAX],auxiliar[MAX];//Cadenas.
    printf("Programa en el que introduces una frase para rescribirla al reves\n\n");
    printf("Introduce tu frase: ");
    gets(frase);
    strcpy(auxiliar,frase);
    j=strlen(frase);
    i=0;k=0;
    while(auxiliar[k]!='\0' && j>=0)
    {
        invertida[i]=frase[j];
        invertida[i+1]='\0';
        i++;k++;j--;
    }
    printf("La frase invertida es:\n%s",invertida);

return 0;
}
```

Se como imprimir la cadena original al revés pero no entiendo por que no me funciona cuando lo intento guardar en otra cadena.
Ayuda por favor.

Comment: La quiero copiar en invertida[MAX] dentro del while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el primer caracter de "invertida" siempre va a ser nulo.

```
j = strlen(frase);
```

Si frase es "hola", j será 4. Pero recuerda que en C los arrays parten de cero, por lo que `j[0] = 'h'`, `j[1] = 'o'`, `j[2] ='l'`, `j[3] = 'a'` y por lo tanto `j[4] = '\0'`.

En la primera línea del while, `invertida[i] = frase[j]`, por lo que `invertida[0] = frase[4]` y ahí queda en nulo el primer caracter.

Haz que

```
j = strlen(frase) - 1;
```

y va a funcionar. Te sugiero hacer el `invertida[i+1] = '\0';` fuera del bucle, va a funcionar igual.

Comment: Gracias por aclarar mi error. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problemas en tu código.

Veo que tu código usa el bucle `while` para el proceso de inversión de cadena, pero esto no suele ser lo habitual. Si bien es cierto que con un bucle `while` funciona, la norma general es usar ese tipo de bucles para tareas repetitivas cuya cantidad de iteraciones no se conoce, mientras que el bucle `for` se usa para aquellas tareas repetitivas cuya cantidad de iteraciones es conocida. En tu caso, siguiendo la norma general deberías usar un bucle `for`.

Utilizas tres formaciones<sup>1</sup> para una tarea que se puede hacer con dos (cadena original y cadena inversa). Por algún motivo crees que necesitas copiar los datos originales en una formación<sup>1</sup> auxiliar para invertirlos, lo cuál gasta más tiempo de proceso (llamar a `strcopy` gasta [*O(n)*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cota_superior_asint%C3%B3tica)) además de gastar más memoria (gastas 1.000 bytes más con el arreglo auxiliar).

No inicializas tus variables, por lo que contienen datos aleatorios y por ello necesitas dar un paso adicional para añadir el [finalizador de cadena](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadena_de_caracteres#Cadenas_din%C3%A1micas_y_est%C3%A1ticas) en `invertida`, que además estás asignando innecesariamente a cada vuelta del bucle haciendo trabajar de más al procesador.

No deberías utilizar variables de una sola letra, en las décadas de los 80 y 90, las pantallas de ordenador soportaban 80 caracteres de ancho y tenía sentido ahorrar espacio en la pantalla; hoy día es absurdo y sólo hará tu código más difícil de entender para tus compañeros y para ti.

Para acabar, estás llamando a `strlen` (también *O(n)*) para averiguar la longitud de la cadena cuando podrías averiguar dicha longitud en el momento de lectura.

#### Propuesta.

Usando [`%n`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) puedes averiguar el tamaño del dato leído, así pues:

```
scanf("%s%n", frase, &j);
```

Pero esto provocaría que leyese hasta el espacio, así que no funcionaría para frases. Para evitar eso puedes usar la captura [`[colección de caracteres]`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) que funciona igual que la captura de [expresiones regulares](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular):

```
scanf("%[0-9a-zA-Z ]%n", frase, &longitud);
```

Teniendo en cuenta todo lo anterior, tu código podría quedar así:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1000

int main()
{
    // Las formaciones estan inicializadas,
    // su contenido inicial esta controlado.
    char frase[MAX] = "", inversa[MAX] = "";
    // Las variables con nombres auto-explicativos son importantes
    int longitud = 0;

    printf("Programa en el que introduces una frase para rescribirla al reves\n\n"
           "Introduce tu frase: ");

    // Leemos la entrada y guardamos su longitud en una sola llamada
    scanf("%[0-9a-zA-Z ]%n", frase, &longitud);

    // Recorremos inversa de inicio a fin y frase de fin a inicio
    for (int l = 0, i = longitud - 1; l != longitud; ++l, --i)
        inversa[l] = frase[i];

    printf("La frase invertida es: %s", inversa);

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VYabdNoEtv0SzzjO)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como arreglo, o en inglés: array.

Answer (score 0):

Observa, inv es la frase invertida y la creo fuera del main porque dentro los espacios vacios del arrglo se llenarian aleatoriamente y eso ocasionaria q mostrase no solo la frase sino tambien un monton caracteres especiales, en el while itero de forma tal que, por ejemplo para la palabra 'hola':

> inv[0] = frase[3], inv[1] = frase[2], inv[2] = frase[1], inv[3] = frase[0]

de esta forma recorremos las dos frases, la inversa de adelante hacia atras y la frase de atras hacia adelante

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char inv[1000];

int main()
{
    char frase[1000];
    gets(frase);
    int l = strlen(frase);
    int c = 0;
    while(c < l){
        inv[c] = frase[l-c-1];
        c++;
    }
printf("La frase invertida es: %s",inv);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué importancia tiene el contenido de `inv` si tan sólo se usa como valor izquierdo?

Comment: La justificación para declarar `inv` como variable estática está cogida con pinzas. Dentro del main es posible inicializar arrays, ya sea con `memset` o en la declaración (`char inv[1000] = { '\0' };`). Por favor, no alientes el uso de variables globales cuando las mismas no son para nada necesarias.

Comment: La declaro de forma global porque estoy acostumbrado a la programacion competitiva, y si se trata de un solo fichero, con un unico objetivo, pienso que asi esta bien